# Flutter click a card from a ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I have a screen in my application where I create a bunch of cards from a map using ListView.builder:

[image]

Now I want to click on those cards and when I do, I go to a new activity and pass the name of the doctor and the rest of his information to the new activity.

How can I do that?

this is a code sample

```
class DocBanner extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 10),
          child: Text(
            'Our Doctors:',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 5.0,
            vertical: 25.0,
          ),
          height: 190,
          width: size.width,
          child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Container(
                width: size.width - 150,
                child: Card(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          '${myList[index]['name']}',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 22,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            letterSpacing: 2,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: size.height - (size.height * 0.99),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '${myList[index]['specialite']}',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: size.height - (size.height * 0.99),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '${myList[index]['city']}',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            color: Colors.red,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            itemCount: myList.length,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: wrap each item in gesturedetector and use navigator inside ontap() of the gesturedetector.

Comment: And how can I get the doctor's name and city that I click to pass them to my new screen ? @Doc

Comment: the other widget which you'll navigate to should have the params in the contructor. Like `NewScreen(this.name)` and pass them as `onTap: ()=>Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder:(_)=>NewScreen(name))` and name here is `'${myList[index]['name']}'`

Comment: Okay, in my case I am using a bubble bottom bar and the new screen is a tab in the bottom bar "as you can see in the picture", Is there a way where I can change the curent tab to a new tab ? @Doc

Comment: the bottombar will have some index to keep track of current page, change that. For this to work, the bottombar should be common to this page and the new page.

Comment: Thank you so much man! @Doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a GestureDetector and navigate to another screen in onTap method, like this:

```
ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return GestureDetector(
          onTap: navigateToOtherScreen(myList[index]),
          child: Container(
....
```